# How comes i get a null pointer in a JSP file on a line which isnt at server side?

Tags: jsp, jqgrid, nullpointerexception, server-side

I have the fallowing JSP file wherein I create a jsGrid in order to menipulate data in my server. Somehow I can't get it running.

```
        <%@page language="java" contentType="text/javascript; charset=windows-1255"

        import="com.dstm.mp.web.event.IServletConstants"
        import="com.dstm.mp.web.model.base.SessionUser"

        import="javax.naming.Context"
        import="javax.naming.InitialContext"

        import="java.sql.Connection"
        import="java.sql.DatabaseMetaData"
        import="java.sql.ResultSet"
        import="java.sql.SQLException"
        import="java.sql.Statement"

        import="javax.sql.DataSource"
        %>

<%@page import="hu.eam.dbtools.DBHandler"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Properties"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="ChartDirector.*" %>


<% String address = "http://192.168.10.48/docuploads/ROADS"; %>

<%   
    String[] astrUpscode  = { "" };

    String strOrder     = request.getParameter("WORKORDERNUM");
    String strOrg     = request.getParameter("ORGANIZATION");
    String SQL = ---Some sql query--    ;   
    String ObjectsSQL = ---Some sql query--;        
ArrayList ObjectsList = null;
    ArrayList Aspects = null;
    ArrayList EventEntries = null;


    SessionUser sessionUser = (SessionUser)session.getAttribute(IServletConstants.USER_BEAN);
    if (sessionUser != null)

    {

        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        Context context = (Context)initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        if (context != null)
        {
            try
            {
                DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/" + sessionUser.getTenantId());
                if (ds != null)
                {
                    DBHandler handler = new DBHandler(ds);                                   

                    ResultSet rs = handler.doQuery(SQL, null);

                    ObjectsList = new ArrayList();
                    EventEntries = new ArrayList();

                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        String ObjectEntry = rs.getString("OBJECT_CODE") +":"+ rs.getString("OBJECT_DESC");
                        if(!ObjectsList.contains(ObjectEntry))
                            ObjectsList.add(ObjectEntry);
                        Object[] EventEntry = new Object[4];
                        EventEntry[1] = rs.getString("DEF_CODE");
                        EventEntry[2] = rs.getInt("SEV");
                        EventEntry[0] = rs.getString("OBJECT_CODE");
                        EventEntry[3] = rs.getString("EXT");
                        EventEntries.add(EventEntry);
                    }



                    handler.close(); 
                }
                else out.println("no datasource<br>");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                out.println("exception=" + e.getMessage() + "<br>");
            }
        }
        else out.println("no context<br>");

        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("<br>");
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("no session user");
    }
%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255"> 
<title>Damage Reporting Grid</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/sunny/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<style type="text/css">@import "<%=address%>/style.css";</style> 

<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="he">


</head>

<body>
<%
out.println("ObjectsList: "+ObjectsList.size()+"<br>");
out.println("EventEntries: "+EventEntries.size()+"<br>");
%>
<table id="GridReporting"></table>
<div id="Pager"></div>
<input type="BUTTON" id="buttonAdd" value="Add" />
<input type="BUTTON" id="buttonAdd" value="Save Changes" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var lastsel2;
jQuery("#GridReporting").jqGrid({
    url:'local',
    height: 250,
    colNames:['Part','Point', 'Event', 'Severity','Perimeter','Note', 'Image 1', 'Image 2'],
    colModel:[
        {   name:'part',     
            index:'part',      
            width:60 ,
            editable:true, 
            edittype:"select",
            editoptions:{
                value:"<%
                if(ObjectsList != null)
                {
                    out.print(ObjectsList.get(0));
                    for( int i = 1 ; i < ObjectsList.size(); ++i)
                    {
                        out.print(";"+ObjectsList.get(i));
                    }
                }
                %>",                
                dataEvents: [{      
                    type: 'change',                      
                    fn: function(e) {                         
                        jQuery("#GridReporting").jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel2,true);                       
                    }                   
                }]
            }
        },
        {   name:'event',    
            index:'event',     
            width:100,
            editable:true, 
            edittype:"select",
            editoptions:{
                value:"Break:Break;Crack:Crack;Bend:Bend",
                dataEvents: [{      
                    type: 'change',                      
                    fn: function(e) {                         
                        jQuery("#GridReporting").jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel2,true);                       
                    }                   
                }]
            }
        },
        {   name:'severity', 
            index:'severity',  
            width:80, 
            editable:true, 
            edittype:"select",
            editoptions:{
                value:"1:1;2:2;3:3;4:4;5:5",         
                dataEvents: [{      
                    type: 'change',                      
                    fn: function(e) {                         
                        jQuery("#GridReporting").jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel2,true);                       
                    }                   
                }]
            }
        },
        {   name:'perimeter',
            index:'perimeter', 
            width:80, editable:true
            edittype:"select",
            editoptions:{
                value:"A:A;B:B;C:C;D:D;E:E",         
                dataEvents: [{      
                    type: 'change',                      
                    fn: function(e) {                         
                        jQuery("#GridReporting").jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel2,true);                       
                    }                   
                }]
            }
        },
        {   name:'note',     
            index:'note',      
            width:80, 
            editable:true, 
            sortable:false,  
            edittype:"textarea", 
            editoptions:{
                rows:"5",
                cols:"20",
                dataEvents: [{      
                    type: 'change',                      
                    fn: function(e) {                         
                        jQuery("#GridReporting").jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel2,true);                       
                    }                   
                }]
            }
        },  
        {   name:'image1',   
            index:'image1',    
            width:80, 
            editable:true,
            edittype:"select",
            editoptions:{
                value:"Pic1:Pic1;Pic2:Pic2;Pic3:Pic3;Pic4:Pic4",         
                dataEvents: [{      
                    type: 'change',                      
                    fn: function(e) {                         
                        jQuery("#GridReporting").jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel2,true);                       
                    }                   
                }]
            }
        },
        {   name:'image2',   
            index:'image2',    
            width:150,
            editable:true, 
            edittype:"select",
            editoptions:{
                value:"Pic21:Pic21;Pic22:Pic22;Pic23:Pic23;Pic24:Pic24",
                dataEvents: [{      
                    type: 'change',                      
                    fn: function(e) {                         
                        jQuery("#GridReporting").jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel2,true);                       
                    }                   
                }]
            }
        }       
    ],

    rowNum:10,
    autowidth: true,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: jQuery('#Pager'),
    sortname: 'part',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    onSelectRow: function(id){
        if(id && id!==lastsel2){
            jQuery('#GridReporting').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel2);
            jQuery('#GridReporting').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
            lastsel2=id;
        }
    },
    editurl: 'connectToDB.jsp',
    caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
}).navGrid('#Pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
$("#buttonAdd").click(function(){
    jQuery("#GridReporting").jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false});
});
var mydata = [

<%
    if(EventEntries != null)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < EventEntries.size() - 1; ++i)
        {
            out.println("{part:"+(((Object[])EventEntries.get(i))[0])+
                        ", event:"+(((Object[])EventEntries.get(i))[1])+
                        ", severity:"+(((Object[])EventEntries.get(i))[2])+
                        ",perimeter:"+(((Object[])EventEntries.get(i))[3])+
                        ",note:try, image1:try, image2:try},");
        }
        int i = EventEntries.size() - 1;
        if(i >=0)
        {
        out.println("{part:"+(((Object[])EventEntries.get(i))[0])+
                        ", event:"+(((Object[])EventEntries.get(i))[1])+
                        ", severity:"+(((Object[])EventEntries.get(i))[2])+
                        ",perimeter:"+(((Object[])EventEntries.get(i))[3])+
                        ",note:try, image1:try, image2:try}");
        }
    }
%>

];
for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
    jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the error which I get:

```
    HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:413)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.custjsp.DamageReportingGrid.DamageReportingGrid_jsp._jspService(DamageReportingGrid_jsp.java:197)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/2.1.3.GA logs.
```

Line 197 isn't in the server section it's in the JavaScript part where I declare the jqGrid columns. How can I find the right line in the JSP code?

Answer (score 1):

The .jsp actually gets compiled to a Java Servlet, so the line number you are seeing is not actually the line of the .jsp file.

I'm not sure where the Java files would be generated to, usually this is a temporary folder somewhere. If you search your JBoss folder for *.java files you may be able to find it that way.